# Как загружать изначально не определённое количество  изображений на сервер  с помощью php?

Tags: изображения, php, upload

Как загружать изначально не определённое количество  изображений на сервер  с помощью php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php+JS(JQuery)
```

Как-то так.

сначала с помощью JS добавляешь новые поля для нужного кол-ва файлов, ну а потом отсылаешь их скопом скрипту на php.

Ну либо каждый новый файл Ajaxом загружать.

можно [тут](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multiupload/) поковырять

Comment: Спасибо , поковыряем)